# Getting info from hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have this hash:

```
[#<Post id: 4, content: "This is a new post", user_id: 12, created_at: "2013-12-16 16:52:33", updated_at: "2013-12-16 16:52:33">]
```

As I understand the hash is in a array, so I can have many hashes in my array which is named `@posts`

Now I would like to print info from the hashes onto a page. For instance it could show the time of creation and then show the content of the post.

Problem is I don't really understand the `for i in array` syntax of ruby. I know I need to make a for loop to get each hash and then another loop to get whatever info I want from there but the ruby syntax is a mistry for me on that topic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#<Post id: 4, content: "This is a new post", user_id: 12, created_at: "2013-12-16 16:52:33", updated_at: "2013-12-16 16:52:33">
```

is not a `Hash`, it's an ActiveRecord object.

You can access an ActiveRecord model property by using the notation:

```
instance.attribute
```

In your case, assuming that `post` is the variable holding the object:

```
post.created_at
```

It looks like the object is stored into an Array. So make sure to extract the item from the array first.

You can look over all the model attributes by asking the instance to return a Hash of attributes and looping over them:

```
post.attributes.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key}: #{value}"
end
```

You can recognize it's an object and not a Hash because the notation for the corresponding Hash would be:

```
 => {:id=>4, :content=>"This is a new post", :user_id=>12, :created_at=>"2013-12-16 16:52:33", :updated_at=>"2013-12-16 16:52:33"}
```

Comment: But what is the difference between hash and ActiveRecord model? Why should I use the second one over the first one i mean?

Comment: If you use ActiveRecord and you query the database using ActiveRecord,  you will get an ActiveRecord model object, not a Hash. I have no idea why you think that in Ruby every object is a Hash. In fact, it's exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop is very rarely used in Ruby. I don’t think it’s that bad to be using it, but the `each` method does decrease the possibility of side effects.

"[For vs Each in Ruby](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2012/02/for-vs-each-in-ruby.html)" explains it well.

Answer (score 1):

I think a read on [Ruby loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) would be beneficial!

As far as the solution to your question is concerned, you can use the `each` method of the `Array` class to loop over each element of the the array:

```
@posts.each do |post| 
  puts post.content
end
```

The above code loops over each element in the `@posts` array, in this case instances of `Post`, then prints the value held by `content` attribute of the `post` object at the current loop index.

Comment: @downvoter, a brief reason for the downvote would be helpful, possibly the answer could be made better with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking:

1. That's not a hash, that's a Post object.
2. Hashes are not Arrays.

In order to get the attributes-value pair of the `post` object, use the `attributes` method:

```
post = Post.first
post.attributes.each do |attr, value|
  puts "#{attr}: #{value}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have inside the array is not a hash, it's a `Post` object:

```
post_array = [#<Post id: 4, content: "This is a new post", user_id: 12, created_at: "2013-12-16 16:52:33", updated_at: "2013-12-16 16:52:33">]

post_array.each do |post|
  p post.id
  p post.content
  #etc
end
```